# Cant boot ubuntu because it cant mount the system disk on startup

Tags: mount, startup

I am new to ubuntu. I have ubuntu 18.04 lts. I was just checking the disk app in which we can edit the mount options. I selected the system partition in which ububtu is installed and by mistake i selected default options for the system disk ( earlier in this disk mount at startup checkbox was checked). So now when i try to turn my laptop on it doesnt start it just shows the ubuntu logo. Is there a way that i can mount my system drive in which Ubuntu is installed manually on startup so that i can cgange those settings afterwards.

Comment: I would boot to a live disc, mount your hard disc, and manually edit /etc/fstab: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use secure boot or disk encryption, You can boot up Ubuntu live from USB drive (select option: try without installing) and launch any tool to fix your issue.

Comment: Can you please suggest a tool to do it. I tried using this (try without installing) and then changed the settings back to mount on startup using the disks tool but it didn't work.